# Why is POINT type layer not displayed correctly in my mapserver map?

Tags: shapefile, mapserver, mapfile

I have 14 shapefiles from same source with the same WKT:

```
PROJCS["GRS_1980_Transverse_Mercator",
GEOGCS["GCS_GRS_1980",
DATUM["D_GRS_1980",
SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",-6000000],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",24],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0],
UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

This WKT does not match any CRS perfectly, but it is very similar to LKS92/Latvia TM:

```
PROJCS["LKS92_Latvia_TM",GEOGCS["GCS_LKS92",
DATUM["D_Latvia_1992",
SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",24],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",-6000000],
UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Only 3 lines are different:

```
# WKT my shapefiles have
PROJCS["GRS_1980_Transverse_Mercator",
GEOGCS["GCS_GRS_1980",
DATUM["D_GRS_1980",

# WKT for LKS92/Latvia TM
PROJCS["LKS92_Latvia_TM",
GEOGCS["GCS_LKS92",
DATUM["D_Latvia_1992",
```

The only issue I am having right now - POINT type layer is not shown correctly on my map. RASTER, LINE, POLYGON type layers are displayed correctly. Layers of type POINT are not shown correctly.

**Image #1** - shows how my map is displayed in mapserver. There is a single black circle outside of map extent area. What I expect to see is something similar to image#2.
[image: MapServer CGI]
**Image #2** - shows how the layers are displayed in QGIS.
[image: QGIS]

**Image #3**  This is what I see when I open the shapefile with QGIS.
[image: objects layer CRS]

I see 2 possible solutions:

- I convert the POINT type shapefile (called places.shp) so that points are shown on the map
- I create a new shapefile with a few POINT type elements which would be in same CRS and work properly in my application.

I have tried both options, used QGis and also [ogr2gui](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92869/how-to-add-a-simple-interface-to-mapserver-cgi-application). No matter what I do, POINT type layer is not shown properly and there is only a single black dot on the map:

mapfile.map:

```
LAYER
    NAME "places"
    DATA places
    STATUS ON
    TYPE POINT
    FEATURE
        POINTS
            1 1
        END
    END
    CLASS
        NAME "places"
        SYMBOL "circle"
        SIZE 16
        COLOR 0 0 0
    END
END

SYMBOL
    NAME "circle"
    TYPE ellipse
    FILLED true
    POINTS
        10 10
    END
END
```

I have tested my application on Mapserver 6.0.3 and 6.4.1.

Edit#1:

This is what QGIS tells me when I check properties of places.shp

```
Extents
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 312500.00,172500.00 : xMax,yMax 762500.00,437500.00
```

extent I have defined in mapfile.map:

```
EXTENT 313187.4 146161.56 766469.92 470367.64
```

Comment: My guess is that the polygon data is using a projected coordinate reference system (CRS) while the point data is using a geographic CRS, aka latitude-longitude, but is defined or assumed to be in the same CRS as the polygon data. That fits with smaller lat-lon values showing up southwest of the other data.

Comment: @mkennedy I see. Any suggestions on how to convert my shapefile from geographic CRS to projected CRS? I just opened the shapefile with QGIS and edited my question, it seems the shapefile has unspecified projection... not sure.

Comment: I'm not familiar with QGIS, but similar questions have been asked before. Try searching with the terms, QGIS and projections. I wish I could help more.

Comment: Can you report the extent of the point file, as stated in the metadata tab of the layer properties when loaded directly into QGIS, and when received via mapserver?

Comment: Added the details. Not sure about the part "when received via mapserver".

Comment: I thought you load the mapserver map as WMS into QGIS. Anyway, that was not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you get the

> ```
> FEATURE
>     POINTS
>         1 1
>     END
> END
> ```

from? This draws a point at x=1 y=1, and not at the coordinates from your shapefile:

[image]

Comment: You are right, this was complete inattention on my part. I misread the documentation about POINTS block. I only needed to use it inside the SYMBOL section and not the LAYER. Thanks!